# Vuejs modal component cannot emit after axios call

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My app is declared like this in app.js

```
Vue.component('sale', require('./components/Sale.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    showModal: false
},
});
```

My main index.blade file @yields the content of my view, and this view simply contains my custom component like this

```
<sale v-if="showModal" @hide="showModal=false"></sale>
```

As you can see, its using the `showModal` to determine when it shows the modal form on top of the main page.

The component in brief is declared here with the form submit option:

```
<template name="sale">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/sales/save" method="POST" @submit.prevent="save">
```

This save method is called correctly and the axios post is working successfully.

I have a standard form inside the modal page and the methods are declared here, which u can see uses axios to post to my controller - again, the post is successful.

```
methods: {
  close(){        
    this.$emit('hide');
  },
  save(){
    console.log('SOLD');
    console.log(this.$data);
    axios.post('/sales/save', this.$data)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.$emit('hide');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('NO ' , error);
      });
  }
}
```

The close method also works as I expect, using the emit to change the value of `showModal`, closing the dialog.

What is not working, is after the post, the `.then` function is giving me an error with the same call to emit: `TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined`.

In fact, the `.catch` is catching the error with the emit inside the `.then` function (not what i was expecting - that it would be catching axios POST errors).

Essentially i'm not sure how to close the modal in the same manner, once the axios call is successful.

Edit: added:

```
mounted() {
  const self = this;
}
```

and changed emit reference

```
self.$emit('hide');
```

I'm not sure i understand the rest of that post

Comment: Looks like a scoping issue. `this` is not a vue instance inside your callback. Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625042/7636961

Comment: thats interesting - are u able to interpret in an answer for my requirement? I thought maybe all i need is in my edit above - i added the mounted self reference and then tried using that but i'm not understanding something

Comment: I've explained my comment in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44630039/7636961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you are using ES2015, you can simply use an arrow function to make sure you don't create a new `this` context:

```
   axios.post('/sales/save', this.$data)
      .then(response => {
        this.$emit('hide');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('NO ' , error);
    });
```

You can find out more about arrow functions at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 4):

You assume `this` refers to Vue instance, but it's not the case in your callback. You lose the `this` reference in a regular function.

You can preserve `this` using one of the following solutions:

1) Use arrow function:

```
methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(text => console.log(this)) // Vue instance
    }
}
```

2) Save `this` to a variable:

```
methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
        const self = this; // save reference
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(function(text) {
            console.log(self) // Vue instance; 'this' points to global object (Window)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You were the first to point out the mistake as you commented a link to the similar issue. That's why +1

Comment: thanks a lot, i had just marked the other answer correct so upped this one as well - i have some reading to do on how/why this all works :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code in your update didn't work is that your `self` is scoped inside `mounted()`, but you're trying to use it inside `methods.save()`.

This would work:

```
methods: {
  save() {
    var self = this;
    axios.post('/sales/save', this.$data)
      .then(function (response) {
        self.$emit('hide');
      })
  //...
```

Or if you're using an ES6 transpiler you could use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to avoid the scoping problem altogether (arrow functions don't bind their own `this`.)

```
methods: {
  save() {
    axios.post('/sales/save', this.$data)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$emit('hide');
      })
```